Upgrading to latest angular 18 with ng2-charts errors on nsg-serve
Upgrading angular 18 with ng2-charts 6.0.1 on running n-serve throws error as below
imports ng2-charts, chart.js,chartjs-plugin-annotation. nothig helps and throws error.
I am trying to use in npn -standard component which is child component for other modules.
    X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/shared/tt-chart/tt-chart.component.html:64:32:
      64 │ ...   <canvas baseChart [type]="pieChartType" class="chart" [datas...
         ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component TTChartComponent.

    src/app/shared/tt-chart/tt-chart.component.ts:11:15:
      11 │   templateUrl: './tt-chart.component.html',
         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/shared/tt-chart/tt-chart.component.html:64:68:
      64 │ ...pe" class="chart" [datasets]="pieChartData[i]" [labels]="chartL...
         ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component EfChartComponent.

    src/app/shared/tt-chart/tt-chart.component.ts:11:15:
      11 │   templateUrl: './tt-chart.component.html',
         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Go through each of the error component and apply the below approach ( This errors happens when the BaseChartDirective is not imported ).
If task component is standalone, add BaseChartDirective to the imports array.
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
...

...
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
      ...
      BaseChartDirective,
      ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class TaskComponent {
    ...

If the task is not standalone, go to the place where you delared the component declarations array. Then import FormModule.
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
...

...
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      BaseChartDirective,
      ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class SomeModule {}

Also ensure you main.ts has the below code.
import { provideCharts, withDefaultRegisterables } from 'ng2-charts';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideCharts(withDefaultRegisterables())],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

The official npm docs provides you step by step on how to configure.

dont find any such to import in ng2-charts 6.0.1  'ChartsModule' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Cannot find module 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

@RajarR updated my answer

this helps . thanks
